# Get cdr of an elt in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I use 2 methods to build a tree based on cons cells.

```
(defun make-tree (nodes)
  (cons nodes NIL))

(defun add-child (tree child)
  (setf (cdr tree) (append (cdr tree) child)))
```

Then I created 4 parameters:

```
(defparameter *root* (make-tree "root"))
(defparameter *a* (make-tree "a"))
(defparameter *b* (make-tree "b"))
(defparameter *c* (make-tree "c"))
```

And I construct the following tree:

```
(add-child *root* *a*)
(add-child *root* *b*)
(add-child *a* *c*)
```

The `*root*` is displayed in the console:

```
CL-USER> *root*
("root" "a" "b")
```

My question is: Is it possible to retrieve `c` from `*root*`? Something like: `(cdr (car (cdr *root*)))` returns an error.

Comment: `c` is not in the tree starting from `*root*`. `add-child` makes a copy when it uses `append`, so `(add-child *a* *c*)` adds the child to `*a*`, but not the copy that's under `*root*`.

Comment: Try using `NCONC` instead of `APPEND` so you don't make a copy.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me to point to some existing querry:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426991/lisp-very-simple-list-question)

Comment: What you want is actually the _opposite_ of that, since you want to share structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NCONC` rather than `APPEND` in `ADD-CHILD`, so you don't make copies of the subtrees.

```
(defun add-child (tree child)
  (setf (cdr tree) (append (cdr tree) child)))
```

With this change, after I do all the other steps, I get:

```
> *root*
("root" "a" "b" "c")
> (car (cdr (cdr (cdr *root*))))
"c"
> (cadddr *root*)
"c"
```

Comment: @Xaving, also note that there are [`nthcdr`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nthcdr.htm) and [`last`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_last.htm).

Comment: Ok. It give an answer to my question. But through that i lost the tree structure (cause b become a child of a). I'm now going into that kind of method [link](http://gajon.org/trees-linked-lists-common-lisp/) in order to manage a tree.

Comment: The problem is that your structure is not really a tree. It's just a linked list, because you only add to the CDR, never the CAR.